# tilt switch to activate power socket

Tags: power, switches, mains

I am after a way to activate a 300 W LED lamp to come on when a trampoline is jumped on and to turn off when the mat goes level again, then back on when jumped on and so forth.

I was thinking tilt switch but unsure if it would work right, so was wondering if anyone had any ideas. I am also open for the idea for someone to make it for me too. I need to make about 85 of them.

Comment: Is this just a "trampoline busy" lamp that goes off when the trampoline hasn't been used for some specified time? Or something more complex?

Comment: Have you thought about ultrasonic from the floor. That way you don't have to attach anything to the trampoline and you don't have to worry about moving parts?

Comment: @RobertFay I like that idea. It's clean, it's small, it's easy to produce 85 times, it's non-dangerous, and the most expensive part is probably the (solid state) relay switching the LED lamp. (though, for the couple tens thousand jumps that one would expect from a trampoline life time, one could argue that mechanical relays would suffice if chosen appropriately.)

Comment: @RobertFay thats sounds perfect. how would i go about it or is this something you could produce?

Comment: @jonk this is for a company in australia they want the light to activate everytime someone jumps on the trampoline so on/offon/off everytime

Comment: Another idea: a PIR (Passive InfraRed) sensor, these are used in nearly all lights that switch on as you approach them. Of course their range is too wide to cover only one trampoline but by adding a tube or such it can be made to only "see" the relevant area. Assuming the lights are above the trampoline that can save long wires between sensor and light (like if you'd use a sensor **under** the trampoline).

Comment: To add another thought, you could consider a horizontally arranged break-beam detector. But this would depend on weight, I suppose. Also, is activity required? Or just standing there good enough? Should detection might be another way. Need more details, really. Too many possibilities in mind.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie the lights are under it so it shines through the mat

Comment: @jonk the idea is that i have 300w coloured floodlight underneath the mat so that when someone jumps on the mat the light turns on and when they are in the air it goes off then back on when they land.  i would really like to keep any switches/sensors underneath so that we have no health and safty issues. the company has 78 trampolines that need setting up with these lights

Comment: Oh so it is only the returning impact, downward only after being in the air, that causes the light to be on. Plus, no activity at all keeps the light on, too?

Comment: @jonk no activity=no light and a jump=light on, while they are in the air the light goes off then back on when they land to jump again

Comment: Sounds like the very first comment I made here. I think we are going in circles and not getting anywhere. Must be me. I'll back away and leave it to others. Thanks. I must be having a problem, myself. I don't want to waste your time further.

Comment: @jonk very similar to your 1st comment when i think about it but timer would have to be something like 1 second then the light goes off.

Comment: That was what I was first thinking! Of course a timer would be involved. But then the rest of the discussion went around some other barn for a while. I'm sure you know what you want. But the communications between us just hasn't worked well. So I plan to let the dust settle. Maybe I'll check back.

Comment: ok, hope someone could help or even build me something as this could be rolled out to other parks i am involved in

Comment: buckle transducer on one of the perimeter cords

Comment: the sensor could be mechanical ..... think of a rubber band tied between the middle of the trampoline and the floor .... a small "flag" on the rubber band could be sensed optically ...... or a strain gauge could be used to measure the pull on the rubber band ..... or the sensor could even be in an ankle bracelet, with an RF link to the lights

Answer (score 1):

The ultrasound idea from @Robert Fay is a great idea!

Assuming that you are not looking to design a PCB for producing 85 units, this is something that you could build using an Arduino or similar. It might be a bit tedious to build 85 times though.....

You could use components such as:

- https://www.adafruit.com/product/4007 (Ultrasound distance sensor)
- https://www.adafruit.com/product/3191 (Relay capable of switching mains power)
- https://www.adafruit.com/product/2771 (Adafruit's Arduino compatible board that will stack neatly with the relay)

Put it all in an enclosure with some holes in the right places and there you go!

You will have to write some code but there are plenty of tutorials online that you can use.

Comment: do you think this is something you would be willing to make and invoice me for?

Comment: @AndrewO'brien I would message you privately about this but I don't think you have enough reputation to chat!

Comment: i own scunthorpe computers my email is on my webpage and so is my contact number just incase im not allowed post here